# CSS does not appear to be cascading for me

Tags: css, wordpress, typography

I have some CSS for a Wordpress blog. I want paragraphs to indent, but blocks of code to align left to the margin.  This is the code that I have---all of these elements appear with a `<div class="postContent"` tag, and Wordpress automatically wraps post text blocks in `<p>` tags.

First, I've set all paragraphs within the div tags to indent:

`.postContent p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-indent: 2.5em;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 1em;
}`

Then, Wordpress sets aside the first paragraph as a `.lead` paragraph. I want that to indent, provided it's not code:

`.postContent p.lead code {
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
}`

That works just fine.  However, all the other code paragraphs are still indenting, so I added this to the stylesheet:

`.postContent p code {
    text-indent: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}`

No dice. The code blocks are still indenting according to the `.postContent p` rule.

Comment: Use firebug or some other form of inspecting the html/css to see which rule is over writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `text-indent` on a `code` element inside a `p` element does not affect the indentation of the `p` element. It does not affect anything, really, since [`text-indent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-indent) applies to block containers only.

If the markup is `<p><code>...</code></p>` so that the `p` contains nothing but the `code`, you can add

```
.postContent p code { display: block; }
```

and then consider what to do with vertical spacing, which may be a bit excessive after the addition (namely margins of `p` plus padding of `code`).

Comment: thanks for that pointer about `<code>` not affecting text-indent. You're right about that. Unfortunately, even with that, I'm still not getting the right layout.

Comment: Nope! i take that back. You're `display: block` fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say without seeing both the source for the html and the actual css code, but I'm guessing your styles are being overridden by a more specific style.

The best thing for you to do is install Firebug in Firefox (really, the best development tools for a browser, IMHO) and inspect the targeted elements.  The inspector should display all the styles being applied to the element.  The overridden styles will have a strikethrough it.  If you see they are being overridden, make your styles more specific.  Otherwise, if you don't see your style listed, then you're not correctly targeting it.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the Firebug plug-in. That's a nice inspector. It's similar to what I use with the built-in Safari developer inspector. Nonethless, the top CSS style, and the only one without a strikethrough is `.postContent p code` and still the text block is indenting. Still though, that for the tool---I'll keep Firefox and Firebug running to check things.